# Is there a way i could set a firestore trigger on a specific field of the firestore document not the whole document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]

My users collection looks like this i want to set a firestore trigger on the online field of all the users so that whenever user is offline the notifications are not sent to device but are stored in another collection and when the user comes online the notification are sent . I can not sent firestore trigger for the whole document becuase the token field can change . Is there any way to achieve that or do i have to store the online status of user in separate collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way i could set a firestore trigger on a specific field of the firestore document not the whole document

No, it's not possible.  You can only trigger on changes to the document as a whole.

If you only want the trigger to take action on changes in a specific field, you can code your function to check for changes in only that field, and ignore all other changes.  It's easy to do this in an onUpdate trigger by comparing the provided [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change) object's `before` and `after` properties with each other to see which fields actually changed.

Comment: I would just store it in a separate collection

Comment: Sure, you can do that if you don't mind changing your document structure.  But the answer to the question is still "no".